# Custom Geoprocessing messages/progress indicator Arcgis 10.2 Modelbuilder?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, geoprocessing

I was wondering if anyone knew a way of customizing the progress indicator for tool developed in Arcgis's model builder. I have a complicated tool, which uses a feature selection iterator, and I would like to either indicate what percent of features have been processed, or output a message with the current count.  I haven't found anything for model builder, but `arcpy` has the [AddMessage](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000005000000) tool.

Comment: You could try incorporating a Python script tool into your model that accesses [SetProgressor etc](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000003z000000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is no if your workflow is entirely within model builder.

If you convert the model to a python script then wire that script into a [ScriptTool](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00150000001r000000), thus exposing it as geo-processing tool within ArcToolbox then you can take advantage of AddMessage and the Progressor (as suggested by @PolyGeo) for providing feedback to the user whilst the script is processing.

Comment: Thank you.  Fortunately, I found a way to significantly simplify the model, so this is less of an issue.